# GridView how to style a group

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

I have a working `GridView` with a grouped items.

```
<GridView x:Name="ItemsGridView" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}" 
      SelectionMode="None" ItemClick="ItemsGridView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="title" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="0" Padding="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>

<GridView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Width="130" Background="{StaticResource CommonBlueBackground}" >
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Key}" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeader}" Margin="0"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</GridView.GroupStyle>
```

Each group looks like this.

[image: No group Styling]

But I want it to look like this.

[image: Styled group]

How do I style each group to have a line on the left hand side as pictured?

Answer (score 0):

The groups in a `GridView` aren't actual controls, but rather a collection of item containers and header controls laid out in the `ItemsPanel` as you can see below.

[image: Groups visual tree]

The easiest solution would be to put a line on the left side of each item through updates to `ItemContainerStyle`.